# Can a large amount of arguments deteriorate performance of a ksh or bash script?

Tags: bash, performance, shell, arguments, ksh

I'm running a KornShell script which originally has 61 input arguments:

```
./runOS.ksh 2.8409 24 40 0.350 0.62917 8 1 2 1.00000 4.00000 0.50000 0.00 1 1 4900.00 1.500 -0.00800 1.500 -0.00800 1 100.00000 20.00000 4 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1 90 2 0.10000 0.10000 0.10000 1.500 -0.008 3.00000 0.34744 1.500 -0.008 1.500 -0.008 0.15000 0.21715 1.500 -0.008 0.00000 1 1.334 0 0.243 0.073 0.642 0.0229 38.0 0.03071 2 0 15 -1 20 1
```

I only vary 6 of them. Would it make a difference in performance if I fixed the remaining 55 arguments inside the script and just call the variable ones, say:

```
./runOS.ksh 2.8409 24 40 0.350 0.62917 8
```

If anyone has a quick/general answer to this, it will be highly appreciated, since it might take me a long time to fix the 55 extra arguments inside the script and I'm afraid it won't change anything.

Comment: I don't know for sure without knowing more about your script and how it's used, but I'd say it's very unlikely to improve performance.

Comment: If you do the same thing with the values, just change where they come from, the difference will be negligible.

Comment: The only real problem is that, because arguments and environment variables share the same block of memory, this many arguments (or rather, the combined length of all the arguments) could pose a problem for operating systems with low limits on the allowed argument/environment size.

Comment: Performance improvement may be negligible, if at all for 61 args. I once had a script with 2^8 args and never had problems. But as a part of refactoring, I changed the script to use flags and received the list of arguments to below 10 (was long ago, don't remember exactly)

Comment: The script simply fixes the values of the input parameters of a series of binary executables which are blackboxes to me.Actually I call this script 440556750 times from Matlab using the "system" function and it takes ~ 0.03 s each time, which translates to 153 days... I'm looking for ways to make it run faster... One possibility was to supress these fix arguments and assign them inside the ksh file.

Comment: Running the system() call is probably taking part of this time.  If you need to run it that many times, perhaps consider using input and output files.

Comment: 440 million system/OS calls?  sounds like you need to rethink your overall design; the time/resources to start/process/clean-up all those OS calls is going to kill you; it may also be that you need to rethink your (shell) script design to reduce the volume of commands processed by the shell script (just a wild guess since we have no idea what's in runOS.ksh); for 440 million system/OS calls I'd want to a) reduce/eliminate OS calls, b) streamline the shell script and c) parallelize the work (eg, put couple dozen cpus to work on 32-cpu host)

Comment: Looking for the overhead, also try replacing your script with `echo "$*"> /dev/null` and `echo "$1" > /dev/null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no performance impact, as you're asking, but I see other threads:

- What is the commandline limitation for your system? You mention 61 input parameters, some of them having a length of 8 characters. If the number of input parameters increases, you might have problems with the maximum command length.
- Are you performing 440 million scripts? That's too much, far too much. You need to consider why you're doing this: you mention needing to wait ±153 days for their execution to finish, which is far too much (and unpredictable).